# Swift Get IP Address from local Device by MAC-Address or Hostname

Tags: ios, swift, macos, networking, ip

I use an ESP8266 in a Local Network. In my IOS App I need the IP Address of the ESP8266 for an HTTP Request. I Know that I can use a static IP but, the ESP8266 is a portable Projekt so maybe I use this in a different Local Network so I don't want to config the IP every time.
So the ESP8266 is connected to a Local Network. And my IPhone with my App is connected to the same network.

I've got the MAC Address and the Hostname of the ESP8266.
How can I get the local IP Address in Swift to do an Http request?

Comment: Yes, You can get local IP. Did you find solution yet ?

Comment: Trying find a way to get the ARP table